# Can i map data getting from MongoDB after lookup and unwind collections

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

[Root Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjibB.png)
[SubClass 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvDsX.png)
[SubClass 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MZaL.png)
[SubClass 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEEAK.png)
[Base Properties Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koZ7V.png)
[Dynamic Lookup Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfr8S.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x410j.png)

Class definitions and error is above. Query and result is below.

collection is `database.GetCollection<T>().Aggregate(); (IAggregateFluent<T>)`

**MongodbQuery:**

```
{
  "aggregate": "Survey",
  "pipeline": [
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "SurveyPart",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "SurveyId",
        "as": "SurveyParts"
      }
    },
    {
      "$unwind": {
        "path": "$SurveyParts",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
      }
    },
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "SurveyPartQuestion",
        "localField": "SurveyParts._id",
        "foreignField": "SurveyPartId",
        "as": "SurveyParts.SurveyPartQuestions"
      }
    },
    {
      "$unwind": {
        "path": "$SurveyParts.SurveyPartQuestions",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
      }
    },
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "SurveyPartQuestionAnswer",
        "localField": "SurveyParts.SurveyPartQuestions._id",
        "foreignField": "SurveyPartQuestionId",
        "as": "SurveyParts.SurveyPartQuestions.SurveyPartQuestionAnswers"
      }
    },
    {
      "$unwind": {
        "path": "$SurveyParts.SurveyPartQuestions.SurveyPartQuestionAnswers",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
      }
    },
    {
      "$match": {
        "IsDeleted": false
      }
    },
    {
      "$sort": {
        "_id": -1
      }
    },
    {
      "$skip": 0
    },
    {
      "$limit": 50
    }
  ]
}
```

**MongoDb Result:**

```
[
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "CreatedOn": "",
        "ModifiedOn": "",
        "CreatedBy": 1,
        "ModifiedBy": 1,
        "OwningUser": 1,
        "StatusCode": 1,
        "IsDeleted": false,
        "Name": "TEST SURVEY",
        "Description": "TEST SURVEY DESCRIPTION",
        "SurveyParts": {
          "_id": 1,
          "CreatedOn": "",
          "ModifiedOn": "",
          "CreatedBy": 1,
          "ModifiedBy": 1,
          "OwningUser": 1,
          "StatusCode": 1,
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "Name": "TEST PART",
          "Description": "TEST PART DESCRIPTION",
          "Order": 1,
          "SurveyId": 1,
          "SurveyPartQuestions": {
            "_id": 1,
            "CreatedOn": "",
            "ModifiedOn": "",
            "CreatedBy": 1,
            "ModifiedBy": 1,
            "OwningUser": 1,
            "StatusCode": 1,
            "IsDeleted": false,
            "Name": "TEST QUESTION",
            "Description": "TEST QUESTION DESCRIPTION",
            "ReferenceCode": "TEST REFERENCE",
            "Type": "RADIO",
            "Order": 1,
            "IsRequired": true,
            "SurveyPartId": 1,
            "SurveyPartQuestionAnswers": {
              "_id": 1,
              "CreatedOn": "",
              "ModifiedOn": "",
              "CreatedBy": 1,
              "ModifiedBy": 1,
              "OwningUser": 1,
              "StatusCode": 1,
              "IsDeleted": false,
              "Name": "TEST ANSWER",
              "Hint": "TEST ANSWER HINT",
              "Tag": "TEST TAG",
              "IsTextField": true,
              "Order": 1,
              "SurveyPartQuestionId": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

I need to map them all at once on the root class. How can i unwind data from this aggregation or is it possible? I spending too many times for this error but i couldnt found anything about it.

Comment: i just found my mistake, unwind is mapping array to an object and its not mapped anymore. i gived up taking nested data from mongodb and i am taking it from entityframework to mongod and after this i am taking all of data in once. that's just resolve my issue. but i am still being curious on to do that :)